# docker compose with create react app procedure undefined environment variables

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have a problem when I declare environment variables in the docker-compose.yml file, but when I try to read them I get "undefined".

My steps:

I created a React app with "create react app", then I ran "eject" (but not changed anything yet). Also, I added Ngix to the docker.

Then I created a Dockerfile and added it to the root:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Then I created the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT=9
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

Then i do "docker-compose up --build" and it works fine.

But when I do somewhere in the app:

```
console.log('process.env.MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT:', process.env.MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT);
```

I get "undefined".

Already tried: 
-Add to Dockerfile:

```
ARG MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT
ENV MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT $MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT
```

and in the docker-compose.yml:

```
  args:
    - MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT=9
```

-Add to compose-docker.yml:

```
environment:
  - MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT=9
```

-Add to compose-docker.yml:

```
environment:
  MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT: 9
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in this [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/2a7fd5a1eac3f78162f28fa49ab69586d70d2e61/docusaurus/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables.md), you need to prefix the variable with `REACT_APP_`, so in your case, it would be `REACT_APP_MAXIMUM_CAMERAS_COUNT`.

Comment: Great. Glad I can help!